# vagrant and puppet security for ssl certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, puppet, vagrant

I'm pretty new to vagrant, would someone who knows more about it (and puppet) be able to explain how vagrant deals with the ssl certs needed when making vagrant testing machines that are processing the same node definition as the real production machines ?

I run puppet in master / client mode, and I wish to spin up a vagrant version of my puppet production nodes, primarily to test new puppet code against.

If my production machine is, say, sql.domain.com I spin up a vagrant machine of, say, sql.vagrant.domain.com. In the vagrant file I then use the puppet_server provisioner, and give a puppet.puppet_node entry of “sql.domain.com” to it gets the same puppet node definition.

On the puppet server I use a regex of something like /*.sql.domain.com/ on that node entry so that both the vagrant machine and the real one get that node entry on the puppet server.

Finally, I enable auto-signing for *.vagrant.domain.com in puppet's autosign.conf, so the vagrant machine gets signed.

So far, so good...

However: If one machine on my network gets rooted, say, unimportant.domain.com, what's to stop the attacker changing the hostname on that machine to sql.vagrant.domain.com, deleting the old  puppet ssl cert off of it and then re-run puppet with a given node name of sql.domain.com ?
The new ssl cert would be autosigned by puppet, match the node name regex, and then this hacked node would get all the juicy information intended for the sql machine ?!

One solution I can think of is to avoid autosigning, and put the known puppet ssl cert for the real production machine into the vagrant shared directory, and then have a vagrant ssh job move it into place. The downside of this is I end up with all my ssl certs for each production machine sitting in one git repo (my vagrant repo) and thereby on each developer's machine – which may or may not be an issue, but it dosen't sound like the right way of doing this.

**tl;dr**: How do other people deal with vagrant & puppet ssl certificates for development or testing clones of production machines ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question completely. But it seems you use _one_ puppet server for both Dev and Prod? Why not use separate, network isolated servers for Prod and Dev? The Dev server can have the same puppet manifest code(perhaps rsyned or git'ed over), but the certs will be signed by a completely _different_ CA. Also, there are few ways to mitigate, but not completely avoid the autosign problem. theforeman.org for example can insert a single _hostname_ in autosign.conf when you provision, and _remove_ it when the cert is signed. This reduces the window which an attacker can use.

Comment: I'll look into theforeman. But yea, I figured i was looking at having to split into two puppetmasters, but I wanted to check this is actually what people do, rather than "this sounds like a good idea"

Comment: I agree with @not-now - each environment should have it's own puppetmaster for all the aforementioned reasons. I'll only note that security architecture is what eventually caused us to prefer Chef Server, which doesn't have a built-in CA and doesn't evaluate templates on the server side. I mostly agree with [this post](http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2012-02/msg00197.html) on the matter.

Comment: @platforms Doesn't Chef push _all_ available recipes to the client, regardless of weather the client actually uses all recipes or not? Doesn't this make it _less_ secure?

Comment: No - when using chef-client with chef-server, the client figures out exactly which cookbooks are needed based on the current runlist for that node, and it downloads just those recipes to /var/chef/cache/cookbooks (configurable). Even then, it's just a cache and these files can be deleted at any time (they will be restored without error on the next chef-client run).

Comment: using chef isn't an option, but it's worth bearing in mind. I think the second puppetmaster route is the logical and safest step. If the development or vagrant puppet master is on localhost or trusted development lan, that makes it a network security issue. Which I can deal with. I guess it was all the SSL certs against a single puppetmaster that got me worried.

Comment: Here's my confusion. Configuration management servers are storing two types of information: deployment scripts, and secrets (Chef has the same issue BTW). Here we are seeing a recommendation to run two servers in order to essentially create a very crude authorization rule governing the secrets. Why not move distribution of secrets into a separate system that has good authz, then a single Puppet / Chef server can serve all the clients.

Comment: what we do is put all the secrets into hiera-gpg, and have a placeholder version of the hiera data in which all passwords are dummy ones. So essentially you just need a common.gpg which has a default for all passwords and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put an answer here for others who may be experiencing a similar query. I ended up using vagrant in a host-only network arrangement using postrouting masquerade (nat) on the host to enable the host-only network to also contact the outside world.

There's a vagrant puppetmaster, which uses autosigning - given that it's on it's own host-only (vboxnet0) network with whatever vagrant puppet client i'm writing code for, it removes most of the security issues i had.

For production, the real (non vagrant) puppetmaster only has the production branch of git, and does not allow any autosigning.